# Well-posedness of flux problems where there's a singularity on the boundary surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields, surface-integrals, divergence-theorem

Let the vector field $\vec{F}$ be defined as the gradient of
$$V=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+z^2}.$$

Now, naively, if we wanted to calculate the flux through a surface defined as an intersection between $S_1:z=x^2+y^2$ and $S_2:z=\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}$, we could either manually calculate

$$\Phi = \Phi_1 + \Phi_2 =  \iint_{S_1} \left(\nabla V\right) \cdot d\vec{S_1} +\iint_{S_2} \left(\nabla V\right) \cdot d\vec{S_2},$$

with suitably oriented surfaces, or, we could use the divergence theorem,

$$\Phi = \iiint_V \operatorname{div} \vec{F} dV.$$

The issue is, there's a singularity at $x=y=z=0$, which is at the very boundary of our surface.

How does the singularity being at the very boundary affect the applicability of the two approaches? Is this problem even well-posed?

Comment: You might explore single-layer potentials in Kellogg's _Potential Theory_.

Comment: @Aruralreader Thank you for the suggestion. Are you sure this is the book - Foundations of potential theory (1929)? Looking through the Contents page and the index I can't seem to find anything related to single-layer potentials, so I'm not sure where to look.

Comment: See Chapter VI.

Comment: @DDADDA In the problem as stated, $S_1$ and $S_2$ are two surfaces whose intersection is a circle not a surface. Such circle does not pass through the origin. What is the original statement? Source?

Comment: @RobertZ I'm not sure if I misspoke somehow and it was not clear from the context. The surface we're interested in is defined as $S_1$ for $0\leq z \leq z_0$ and $S_2$ for $z_0<z\leq R$, where $z_0$ is the value of $z$ for which the two surfaces intersect. I can provide a graph if it's not clear what I mean.

Comment: The original statement just gives $V$ and the two functions of $z$ and asks for the flux to be calculated in two different ways. The source is an exam problem that I thought was not well-posed.

Comment: The flux through $S_1$, considered as an improper integral, is divergent. Probably there is a typo in this exam problem.